# Upload images to another directory in CodeIgniter

Tags: image, codeigniter, file-upload, directory

Is it possible to upload images to anywhere other than the default **upload/thumb** directory in CodeIgniter? We have our form in the root directory but we would like the photos sent to upload/thumb in another directory.

For example, current upload location: `www.mysite.com/upload/thumb/`

We would like the files to be sent from the root directory for here `` `www.mysite.com/123/upload/thumb/ ``

I have changed the upload paths in the controller files... to no avail. What else should be changed? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read the docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html). You can set it using the `upload_path` key in the config array:

```
$config['upload_path']   = './123/upload/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size']      = '100';
$config['max_width']     = '1024';
$config['max_height']    = '768';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Comment: I've already tried `'./cs/upload/thumb/';` , `'/cs/upload/thumb/';` and `'cs/upload/thumb/';` to no avail. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JoeW - What do you mean by `to no avail`? Do you get an error, or they're still uploading to the original location?

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+no+avail The original location is still being used.

Comment: It seems the upload path for this particular part of our site is controlled within an encrypted home_model.php file which is a crazy place for this. I will contact the original vendor. Thanks for taking the time to answer this though.

Comment: Or in theory I should be able to change the **base_path** directory in `application/config/config.php` I would have thought? But still this doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Set the source path (where the file was saved)

```
$sourcePath = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
```

Set the target path  (this is where you want it to go)

```
$targetPath = "../cs/upload/thumb/".$_FILES['userImage']['name'];
```

Move the file

```
move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)
```